# Why is entropy of system same for reversible and irreversible processes?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, reversibility, carnot-cycle

I read that entropy change of universe is zero in a reversible process  but positive in a irreversible process,then doesn't it mean that entropy change of system of both the processes must be different?

I also read that in a reversible cycle, entropy change is zero for example a carnot cycle,and entropy change in an irreversible cycle is positive for example if we consider friction in a carnot cycle.
Doesn't this show that entropy change of system in both processes is different?

Comment: I don't think I understand your question. But note that the *change* in entropy is zero for a reversible process, not the entropy itself...

Comment: Yes i meant entropy change

Comment: Yes... The entropy change for a reversible versus an irreversible process is different (*by definition*)...

Comment: I meant the entropy change in both the processes.We say that entropy change is a state function and hence should not depend on path taken.

Comment: That's right, but a reversible process ends up in a different state to an irreversible process, so the paths are necessarily different...

Comment: Ohkay so we can calculate entropy change due to an irreversible process just by calculating the entropy change assuming the final state is achieved by a reversible process and since it is a state function,we can equate those values?

Comment: An irreversible process changes more than one entropy and if you are looking at a typical thermodynamic process with two temperature baths (or sources of matter in case of chemical reactions), then you can transfer as much excess entropy as you like in addition to the changes of the system between the two temperature baths.

Comment: Please provide a reference for the change in entropy of the working fluid in an irreversible cycle not being zero.  If entropy is a state function, the change in entropy of the working fluid undergoing a cycle must be zero, irrespective of whether the process is reversible.

Comment: I was studying about entropy from khan academy, and in that he proved that in a carnot cycle entropy change is always zero when we complete a full cycle and hence entropy is a state function.But when we consider an irreversible cycle for example,if we decide to include friction energy lose when piston moves up and down,the process will become irreversible and in this case when we complete a full cycle ,from initial state and back to it,the entropy change is not zero and hence Sal concluded that entropy as a state function makes sense only for reversible processes.

Comment: And after that he explained that we can still talk about entropy change in irreversible processes and we can calculate it by assuming that the initial and final state of the process whose entropy is to be calculated is achieved by reversible process and we can equate those two since entropy is a state function.Isn't he contradicting what he said before?

Comment: In an irreversible cycle, the entropy change of the universe (working fluid plus surroundings) is greater than zero, but the entropy change for the working fluid is still zero.  So the increase in entropy for an irreversible cycle must lie entirely within the surroundings.  When he was talking about the entropy change for an irreversible process (and how to determine it), he must have been referring only to the entropy change of the system and not to the entropy change of the surroundings.

Answer (score 1):

I think entropy change is zero if the system undergoes reversible and adiabatic process at the same time(isentropic process)